# Access 0 index xml property in php

Tags: php, xml, parsing, simplexml

I have written a program which read an XML file and provide me an array. So I further perform my operations but I am not able to get the value of 0 index.

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("app_string.xml");

foreach ($xml as $value) {
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($value);
}
```

That is the output:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object (
    [@attributes] => Array
        (
            [name] => app_name
        )

    [0] => My Data )
```

I tried with

```
$value->{0}
```

and

```
$value['0']
```

Not getting the desire data.

How can I get `My Data` from `[0] => My Data`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To retrieve the element data, you can simple cast the XML element to a string, as in:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("app_string.xml");

foreach ($xml as $value) {
    echo "<pre>";
    $data = (string)$value;
    echo $data;
}
```

Comment: Is there any other way to get the data? Like I can get attribute like `$value->attributes()->name;`.

Comment: Yes, that would be `$value->getName()`

Comment: @KapilSharma `$value->attributes()->name;`, which can also be written `$value['name'];`, gives you an object representing the attribute. To get the text contents, you would write `(string)$value->attributes()->name;`. What may be confusing you is that `echo` casts to string automatically, so you'll find that  `echo $value` works as well. In fact, so will `echo $value[0]`. However, `print_r` will always tell you you've got an object.